SVG & PDF render performance
We were using SVGs in our iOS project for our assets, but it looks like it was making our app much more heavy and now we also found that is making our app slower (causing flickering when scrolling).
After some testing, we did a comparison between using PNGs, SVGs, PDFs, HEICs:

201ms   - SVG with preserve vector data (and 1534ms in extreme cases!!)
4ms     - SVG without preserve vector data
215ms   - PDF with preserve vector data
4ms     - PDF without preserve vector data
5ms     - PNG very big resolution
96ms    - HEIC (which is weird... in other assets is 5ms)

Test code:
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
(0..<10).forEach { _ in
    UIImage(named: imageName)!.draw(in: frame)
}
let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
print("TIME: \(Int(diff * 1000))ms - \(imageName)")

We finally changed to only use PNG, which seems to be 40x faster. We used ImageOptim to optimize size, and at the end our Assests.car shrank from 5mb to 1mb.
So, after our tests... is there any point to use vectorial images in iOS? Maybe only when you really need to make an image very big without caring about performance?
Are my tests ok or I am missing something? Thank you!

You may want to post a simple project with example SVG, PDF and PNG files -- somewhere such as GitHub. That way, we can download and run your tests to see if we can give you any insight.

Hey thanks for the response. I will work on that these days. Thanks!

Similar problem here.  We have several hundred SVG images used as puzzle images. The Xcode auto-generated PNGs grow our asset catalog size from 4 to 12MB.  The kicker is we can't even tell if/when iOS chooses to use the PNGs. Presumably if we want an exact size image it will (eg 100x100), but what about 88x88?  For larger image sizes it does seem to use the vector version (judging by image quality). Performance is fine as is, so we're wondering how we can delete the PNGs completely (stop Xcode from auto-generating them).  Fun stuff :/

We ended up NOT using "Preserve Vector Data", which is what was causing all this. This way Xcode converts SVG to rasterized images at build time with the size that was determined on the SVG file. There is no real native support for SVGs in iOS from what I have tested. If you use the "Preserve Vector Data", you will end up having rasterized+vectors files (making the app heavier) and possibly adding performance issues since it is not hardware accelerated (maybe noticeable in scrolls with cells with many images). I will try to make repo and an article about my findings once I get some free time.
